# after changing name of macOS home directory vscode 'code' command only works as sudo

Tags: linux, macos, path, visual-studio-code, sudo

I recently had a hard drive crash and restored from a backup. When creating a new user account to restore from time machine into,  I had accidentally set my home folder to have a space in it (i.e. `/Users/w 1/`, which was intolerably annoying to deal with afterward), so I created a new admin user, logged in as that user, and changed the Users / Groups settings and folder name, afterward logging back into the original admin account.

Aside from Docker needing to restart and having some trouble with installing Jenkins plugins within Docker (was able to manually download them, just not with the auto wizard), and Dropbox failing out, everything seems to be fine. Little snitch and other system preferences all needed reconfiguration.

**The problem is:**

Disk permissions were thrown off so I `sudo chmod -R 755 /Users/w/`'d, no problems there. However my vscode `code` sh command doesn't work anymore unless I run it with sudo. No other shell commands have trouble without sudo. I removed it from path and readded it from within vscode, but it's not working.

Ideas? It's more just annoying than anything, other than the "not recommended to run vscode as root" thing.

...also worth nothing - I can see the little vscode icon pop up for just a second in the menubar at the bottom of my screen and then disappear instantly...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a chmod you should do a sudo chown to make your new user account the owner of all of those files and permissions are not necessary going to be the same for your entire user profile. For simplicity's sake you may want to create a hard link from /Users/w 1/ to /Users/w/, otherwise you are going to have a hell of a time dealing with hard coded profile links.

Edit:
Specifically for the vscode issue, it appears your terminal session does not have access to your .bash_profile where the application path is added to your Path environmental variable. Either fix the ownership and permissions on this file or follow the instructions https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac and add "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin" to your path environmental variable.

Comment: That should have fixed the issue with .bash_profile. You need to add the path variable to the file. See here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac